# Google Form Abandonment

Tags: google-forms

If someone abandons a Google Form survey before submitting, can I still see their responses up until the point where they dropped off?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible due to the fact that form was not submitted (eg. completed or sent to the spreadsheet). Data from an abandoned form are simply "lost" and not recorded in the final results.